Moving from Java 1.8 to Java 11, with IIOP Corba gives "Corba no permission"
Target is:

Moving client (portlet) code from Java 1.8 to Java 11 - see testcase below.
Server Payara 5 running on java 11, but Session Beans compiled in Java 1.8.
Communication via IIOP:Corba.

Above are limitations I can't replace.
Current Java 1.8 code that works (against Payara 5 running on Java 11):
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
String jndiName = "corbaname:iiop:127.0.0.1:3700#java:global/Portal/Portalejb/PortalService!se.services.portal.PortalServiceHome";
PortalServiceHome home = (PortalServiceHome)ctx.lookup(jndiName);
PortalService ps = home.create();

Test code with Java 11 that fails (against Payara running on Java 11):
Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.initial", "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass", "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBImpl");
Context ctx = new InitialContext(props);
String jndiName = "java:global/Portal/Portalejb/PortalService!se.services.portal.PortalServiceHome";
PortalServiceHome home = (PortalServiceHome)ctx.lookup(jndiName);
PortalService ps = home.create();

Looking up Home interfaces works, but it fails on create with:
java.rmi.AccessException: CORBA NO_PERMISSION 0 No; nested exception is: 
org.omg.CORBA.NO_PERMISSION: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.NO_PERMISSION:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecServerRequestInterceptor.handle_null_service_context(SecServerRequestInterceptor.java:441)
at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecServerRequestInterceptor.receive_request(SecServerRequestInterceptor.java:460)

Same session bean and same Payara 5 in both cases.
Since several javax function has gone in Java 11 new libs are introduced in the client. Artifacts that are new: glassfish-corba-omgapi, javaee-api and gf-client.
Any suggestion on how to proceed to solve this.

Common Object Request Broker Architecture (CORBA) was removed from Java 11.
Oracle asked for third parties to step in, but nobody did (as far as I know).
Payara 5 supports Java 8 as well as Java 11. Perhaps you should continue using Java 8 if it continues to receive fixes. You can choose any of several possible JDK vendors: Adoptium by Eclipse Foundation, Amazon, Microsoft, Oracle, BellSoft, Azul Systems, SAP, Red Hat, IBM, and more.
See Is there a replacement library for CORBA in JDK 11
No CORBA feature is bundled in any modern JDK/JRE.
See Comment below about Glassfish and Payara including CORBA functionality. Support available.
See the Jac ORB project, a free Java implementation of the OMG CORBA standard.

This is sad; CORBA was good technology. Unfortunately the industry instead chose unwisely to re-invent CORBA as Web Services, and is doing so again now with JSON.

Thanks for the input. Glassfish(Payara) has a package with support for Corba (glassfish-corba-omgapi) which I am currently testing. Maybe there is more.

Regarding platform: we have a new client that requires Java 11+ and an old backbone that doesn't compile in Java 11. So we are stuck with this combo. We are moving from Corba, but not at the speed I would like.

Hi, it sure looks like Payara includes CORBA implementation and works even on Java 11, while your client app, which doesn't run on Payara, doesn't contain CORBA on Java 11, because it's not provided by Java 11 anymore. In theory, it should be possible to add GlassFish CORBA library to your client to replace the CORBA functionality that was removed in Java 11. If you need help with that, we at OmniFish can help. We drive the development of GlassFish and provide support services for it.

Maybe this JacORB issue with the linked PR can help, see https://github.com/JacORB/JacORB/issues/314
